# Android MediaPlayer start hangs UI, even if called from a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer

I have been trying to get a workaround for this problem the whole day today, and too many hours on other days. But today i was at least able to refine the problem.

I have a .acc audio file with a screwed up header, lets call it `"BadFile"` : According to a logcat dump from android native C code that i noticed the other day, the header says the file has 44.100Hz, but the data itself has 0Hz.

I have an arraylist of files that represents a playlist and an int pointer that defines what song to play at a given moment. As i queue in the playlist some songs, lets say GoodFile1, GoodFile2, BadFile, GoodFile3, GoodFile4 etc..., with the pointer set at 0, GoodFile1 starts playing.

//this is called from Thread.currentThread().getId() == 1

```
 private void play() {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    playCicle();
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }

private synchronized void playCicle() {
        Log.e("THREAD" , "T:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Log.e("TRYING TO PLAY", playlist.get(playPointer).getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            if(progressSenderRunnable != null) {
                progressSenderRunnable.stop();
            }
            if(myMP != null) {
                myMP.release();
            }
            myMP = new MediaPlayer();
            myMP.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            myMP.setDataSource(mService, Uri.parse(Uri.encode(playlist.get(playPointer).getFile().getAbsolutePath())));
            setOnPrepareListener();
            myMP.prepare();
            setOnCompletionListener();
            setOnErrorListener();
            myMP.start();
            sendImPlaying();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Log.e("METHOD " , "EXITING");
    }

private void setOnCompletionListener() {
        myMP.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                Log.e("onCompletionthread" , "T: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!userSetPlayPointerNext && !userSetPlayPointerPrevious) {
                            playPointer++;
                        }
                        userSetPlayPointerNext = false;
                        userSetPlayPointerPrevious = false;
                        if(playPointer < playlist.size()) {
                            play();
                        }
                        else {
                            if(progressSenderRunnable != null) {
                                progressSenderRunnable.stop();
                            }
                            if(myMP != null) {
                                myMP.release();
                            }
                            sendImStopped();
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

When it starts playing the first song i click the next button resulting on a call to this next method by Thread with ID 1.

```
void playNextSong() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(isPlaying() && playPointer < playlist.size() - 1) {
                    playPointer++;
                    userSetPlayPointerNext = true;
                    myMP.seekTo(myMP.getDuration() - 1);
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

GoodFile2 started playing.
Then i start spamming the next buton, and the UI just hangs. After this hang i can spam the next button just fine (since we got past the BadFile).

```
10-17 21:18:23.734: E/THREAD(24021): T:41
10-17 21:18:23.734: E/TRYING TO PLAY(24021): /mnt/sdcard/Music/BadFileTest/01_Compay Segundo - Te Apartes De Mi.mp3
10-17 21:18:23.744: E/METHOD(24021): EXITING
10-17 21:18:23.744: E/PREPARED(24021): PREPARED
10-17 21:18:24.364: E/Service rcv(24021): 17
10-17 21:18:24.364: E/back in handler(24021): 1
10-17 21:18:24.384: E/onCompletionthread(24021): T: 1
10-17 21:18:24.384: E/THREAD(24021): T:45
10-17 21:18:24.384: E/TRYING TO PLAY(24021): /mnt/sdcard/Music/BadFileTest/02 - Blue.aac
10-17 21:18:24.394: E/METHOD(24021): EXITING
10-17 21:18:24.724: E/PREPARED(24021): PREPARED
10-17 21:18:28.914: E/onCompletionthread(24021): T: 1
10-17 21:18:28.924: E/THREAD(24021): T:48
10-17 21:18:28.924: E/TRYING TO PLAY(24021): /mnt/sdcard/Music/BadFileTest/02_Ibrahím Ferrer - Ay Candela.mp3
10-17 21:18:28.944: E/METHOD(24021): EXITING
10-17 21:18:29.074: E/PREPARED(24021): PREPARED
```

At: 10-17 21:18:23.734 you can see GoodFile1 almost being played by thread with id 41

At: 10-17 21:18:24.364: you can see the Service reciving the op_code for `playNextSong()`.

At: 10-17 21:18:24.364:: you can see the main thread returning from the call to `playNextSong()`

Meanwhile thread with id 45 is loading BadFile and exits the `playNextSong()` method.

Now here is the hang:

10-17 21:18:24.724: E/PREPARED(24021): PREPARED

10-17 21:18:28.914: E/onCompletionthread(24021): T: 1

During this 4s, my UI is un-usable. What i see is that even that the setOnCompletion listener wasn't called from the main thread, its the main thread that gets called on the listener invocation, altough im not sure if this is related to the hang.

I may have too much unnecessary threading at the moment, but i was trying to get the most work done away from the main thread as possible. I will change this in the future.

Also the synchronized keyword is being useless at the moment i think, since im using on completionListener to start the new thread to play the next song.

If anyone got an ideia of what i am doing wrong that is making me pay those 4s i'd be much appretiated!

**Edit:**

Foud the console dump i was talking about, this warnings wont show in my package logcat filter:

```
10-18 07:46:37.055: E/THREAD(10772): T:21
10-18 07:46:37.055: E/TRYING TO PLAY(10772): /mnt/sdcard/Music/BadFileTest/02 - Blue.aac
10-18 07:46:37.075: I/StagefrightPlayer(157): setDataSource('/mnt/sdcard/Music/BadFileTest/02 - Blue.aac')
10-18 07:46:37.625: V/OMXCodec(157): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.Nvidia.aac.decoder'
10-18 07:46:37.625: V/OMXCodec(157): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.TI.AAC.decode'
10-18 07:46:37.625: V/OMXCodec(157): Successfully allocated software codec 'AACDecoder'
10-18 07:46:37.625: E/PREPARED(10772): PREPARED
10-18 07:46:37.625: E/start(10772): before
10-18 07:46:37.625: W/AACDecoder(157): Sample rate was 44100 Hz, but now is 0 Hz
10-18 07:46:37.625: E/start(10772): after
10-18 07:46:37.635: W/AACDecoder(157): Disable AAC+/eAAC+ since upsampling factor is 1
10-18 07:46:37.635: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.635: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 30, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 30, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 30, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 30, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 30, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 30, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 30, substituting silence
10-18 07:46:37.645: W/AACDecoder(157): AAC decoder returned error 20, substituting silence
```

Curiously, this codec error warning goes for about more 4s, Just the amount of time that my main thread is hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not my client code, its the AAC decoder that is hogging my CPU while trying to decode BadFile. just confirmed this with a CPU Monitor. Therefore its not my main thread that is hanging, its the whole system.

Comment: same issue with me, so is there any solution? i have posted my scenerio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432546/ticker-stuck-when-movie-prepare-method-calls